# Remove port number from URL web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-web-api

I've created a web API and hosted it on IIS 7.0, but the default port hosts another web application.  Therefore, I specified another port for the WEB API. The issue is how the web API is accessed as it includes the port number along with the URL. I want to remove this port dependency or at least hide it.

So instead of ***http://website:26018/api/products?brand_id=2,3***

I want it to be accessible from a URL like this:

***http://website/api/products?brand_id=2,3***

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Put it on port 80 ...

Comment: If you want it on a specific port you will have to specify that port or use port 80 (which is the default). Otherwise you could create a firewall rule to map external traffic from abc.whateever.com to anything you like internally

Comment: One option you have is setting up a host header in IIS, depending on whether this is local, internal or public depends on how complicated this is.

Comment: The port is required for IIS to bind to the correct website. If you wanted to remove the port dependency and assuming that the URL is for an API, My advice would be to put the base API URL into AppConfig/WebConfig and then build the API request URL without depending on any of the URL.

Comment: Why are your running your apps on different ports, btw?

Comment: I'm assuming that the other app which is using port 80 is a port hog and is listening on all host headers... Otherwise, can you share the port and just use host headers to differentiate the applications?

Comment: Sorry about spamming the comments but just not sure about the exact environment, you could setup a reverse proxy in front of the IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

The http specification [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.txt) (Section 3.2.2) states that

> If the port is empty or not given, port 80 is assumed.

Therefore, to omit the port number, you will have to put your application on port 80.

IIS allows you to redirect traffic coming from a specific DNS address to your application. Take a look at this article: http://www.visualwin.com/Host-Header/